# Refresh value in checkbox upon popupmenu in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

The data I have is called in the "checkbox1" as "fulldata" where I have the X and Y values located in a data matrix:

Code:

```
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
function popupmenu1_CreateFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles)
if ispc && isequal(get(hObject,'BackgroundColor'), get(0,'defaultUicontrolBackgroundColor'))
    set(hObject,'BackgroundColor','white');
end



function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)

fulldata=handles.fulldata;
x1=fulldata(:,1);
x2=fulldata(:,3);
x3=fulldata(:,5);
Y1=fulldata(:,2);
Y2=fulldata(:,4);
Y3=fulldata(:,6);

     contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String'); 
     popupmenu1value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
     switch popupmenu1value
        case 'plot1'
           plot(X1,Y1)
        case 'plot2'
           plot(X2,Y2)
        case 'plot3'
           plot(X3,Y3)
        end
```

Dependent on the popupmenu1 selection I want to plot on of the specified plots. The selection is working fine when I first select the value in the popupmenu followed by the checkbox. However, if I change the value of the popupmenu, I have to uncheck and recheck the checkbox to refresh the new selection.  Is there a way where the checkbox function is refreshed automatically when I change the popupmenu value, so I dont have to uncheck and recheck it? Thanks a lot...

Comment: I doubt this code works; it is missing several `end` keywords. In any case, have a look at `addlistener`

Comment: You can simply insert a conditiin to the popupmenu_callback function: if the checkbox is checked already, call checkbox1_callback.

Comment: The `end` is optional for functions in certain cases, like this one.  It is certainly more readable (imho) to have the `end` here, but is not necessary for the code to work ([more info](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/end.html)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  It's probably easiest to put your plotting code into a separate function that you call from both callbacks in the same way.  It will make the code a bit cleaner and easier to work with.

```
function popupmenu1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    myPlotFcn(handles);    
end

function checkbox1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    myPlotFcn(handles);    
end

function myPlotFcn(handles)
    isChecked = get(handles.checkbox1,'value');
    if(isChecked)
        contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
        popupmenu1value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
        switch popupmenu1value
            case 'plot1'
                plot(X1,Y1)
            case 'plot2'
                plot(X2,Y2)
            case 'plot3'
                plot(X3,Y3)
        end
    end
end
```

I'm not sure where you are getting your `X1` and `Y1` from, but this should work if your current code is working.

**UPDATE**
If you want to control several checkboxes with the `myPlotFcn`, then you need to add logic for each checkbox within that same function.  Assuming you have different axes for each checkbox (e.g. handles.axes1, handles.axes2) and a way of getting the x, y data for each case, then it could look like this:

```
function myPlotFcn(handles)
    is1Checked = get(handles.checkbox1,'value');
    if(is1Checked)
        contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
        popupmenu1value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
        switch popupmenu1value
            case 'plot1'
                plot(handles.axes1,X1,Y1)
            case 'plot2'
                plot(handles.axes1,X2,Y2)
            case 'plot3'
                plot(handles.axes1,X3,Y3)
        end
    end
    is2Checked = get(handles.checkbox2,'value');
    if(is2Checked)
        contents = get(handles.popupmenu1,'String');
        popupmenu1value = contents{get(handles.popupmenu1,'Value')};
        switch popupmenu1value
            case 'plot1'
                plot(handles.axes2,X1,Y1)
            case 'plot2'
                plot(handles.axes2,X2,Y2)
            case 'plot3'
                plot(handles.axes2,X3,Y3)
        end
    end
    % And so on for however many you have
end
```

You can't define the same function over and over again however with the same name unless you make it a nested function (this means you need to add `end` to all of your current functions (like I have in the code), and then define the `myPlotFcn` inside each checkbox#_Callback function, within the ends.  It's messy.

Comment: Hey information,

Thanks a lot for your answer. I been a bit busy so have not tried your code yet, but I will later today. Until then I will just let you know that I have updated the question to describe how I find the X,Y values. The code is probably a bit clumsy, so if you have any ideas please let me know. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey information. Your code works perfectly. Thanks a lot. I do however have a question for you. Please see below: